Qt lossless QPixmap from pdf
using QPixmap("pdf_filename"); my pixmap lose a lot of the pdf quality, any way I could avoid the loss ?
I tryed to convert thr pdf to png with an online converter and when I load the png with QPixmap there is no loss.

I believe that QPixmap (or, to be precise, QImageReader) uses QPdfDocument to render a pdf, with default and, possibly, unacceptable sizes. I'd suggest you to work with the QtPdf modules, possibly by creating a QPdfDocument and then calling render() with an appropriate size that suits your needs.

Thanks, usoing QPdfDocument  to save the pdf as a png and then load the png do the trick

Good. Then I suggest to answer your own question by clicking the related button in this page (providing an explanation and a basic [mre]), so that it will be useful to others too.

Thanks to musicamante advices here is my working code, it get a pdf, convert it to a png to keep quality, load the png and display it into a label (skipping save seem to cause a quality loss in qt 6.5) :
 void importPDF(){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Import PDF"),"/home",tr("*.pdf"));
    QPdfDocument* pdf = new QPdfDocument();
    pdf->load(fileName);
    pdf->render(0,pdf->pagePointSize(0).toSize()).save("temp.png");
    QPixmap pix("temp.png");
    label->setPixmap(pix->scaled(label->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation));
}

